# What does AT&T syntax do about ambiguity between other mnemonics and operand-size suffixes?

Tags: syntax, x86, sse, att, mmx

In AT&T syntax instructions often have to be suffixed with the appropriate operand size, with `q` for operations on 64-bit operands. However in MMX and SSE there is also `movq` instruction, with the `q` being in the original Intel mnemonic and not an additional suffix.

So how will this be represented in AT&T? Is another `q` suffix needed like

```
movqq %mm1, %mm0
movqq %xmm1, %xmm0
```

or not?

And if there are any other instructions that end like AT&T suffixes (like `paddd`, `slld`), do they work the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT&T syntax basically doesn't do anything about conflicts between mnemonic+suffix vs. other mnemonics.  **Register operands always disambiguate between a `mov` mnemonic with a `q` operand-size suffix vs. the `movq` mnemonic**

`movq %xmm0, %xmm0`, `movq %rax, %xmm0`, and `movq %xmm0, %rax` are 3 different opcodes that all use the same mnemonic (`movq` in both Intel and AT&T syntax).

A suffix is not allowed on the `movq` mnemonic: `Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'movq'`.  This is normal because there's no possible ambiguity with respect to *operand-size*.  `movq` always moves 64 bits, so a `q` suffix would be redundant.

---

Does this make parsing AT&T harder than parsing Intel syntax?  Well before MMX even existed (thus also before x86-64),  `movl` was still the mnemonic for [6 different opcodes (Intel's insn set ref manual entry for `mov` lists them all, with their numeric opcode)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html):

- `MOV r/m32,r32`
- `MOV r32,r/m32` (assembler can choose either opcode if both operands are regs)
- `MOV r32, imm32` (short form)
- `MOV r/m32, imm32` (with a modr/m, usable for memory operands).
- also `MOV moffs32,EAX` and `MOV EAX,moffs32`, as an optimization (no ModR/M) for storing/loading with a 32-bit absolute address.

And that's not counting mov to/from segment, control, and debug registers.  Just like with `movq %xmm0, %rax`, AT&T syntax has always had to deal with `mov %ds, %ax`.

Adding a few more forms with different registers to disambiguate is probably not much harder to parse.

---

Besides that, operand-size suffixes are optional when registers determine the operand-size anyway.  `mov %rax, %rcx` is legal, and a suffix is only needed for moving an immediate to memory.  `mov $1, (%rsi)` is illegal because neither operand implies an operand-size, and there's no suffix to make it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

`movq` was introduced with MMX to facilitate movement of quadwords between MMX registers and non-MMX registers.  It's a general-purpose opcode; you can move a quadword between an mmx register and any other register (mmx or non-mmx), or even between non-mmx registers.

In other words, there aren't two different opcodes.  Consequently, the syntax is always `movq`.

Comment: but in Intel syntax there are 2 different mnemomics: `movq`/`movd` for MMX and `mov` for normal registers

Comment: Even for quadwords?  Try `movq` for two ordinary registers; if that doesn't work, then report back here, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Yes. You use `mov rax, rbx`, not `movq rax, rbx` even when they are quadwords

Comment: Then limit your use of `movq` to quadword moves that only involve mmx registers.  `movq` is the name of an opcode; there's no expectation (at least on my part) that the `q` has any special meaning other than it is a letter in the opcode.

Comment: Try `movq` on two non-mmx registers; I suspect it will still work.

Comment: It doesn't work in Intel syntax but will work in AT&T if the regisers are 64 bits. It's just "counterintuitive" to me in this case when AT&T uses only 1 mnemonic for many cases when it's usually more "complicated" than Intel and uses separate mnemonics for different instructions

Comment: Why would you have the expectation that two completely different assemblers would behave exactly the same way?  Perhaps its counter-intuitive, but it sounds like it is what it is.